# Global Macro Investing textbooks and reading list

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

What is a good reading list for Global Macro investing? What does Bridgewater, Bervan Howard, Soros, AQR etc. use to teach their staff about macroeconomic investing?

Let us assume a top-class education at the undergraduate level in economics, maths, and economic history so as to avoid the common recommendations of not very useful introductory texts.

Note: Global Macro Investing involves expressing views on commodities, rates, FX, Real Estate, Equities and other asset classes using ownership, futures, or options to find relative value and generate alpha on a global basis.

For example: Short USDTRY on asset outflows from turkey due to geo-political risk and US tightening cycle compared to TRY printing/easing.

Comment: What do you mean by "macroeconomic investing"?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Edited to "Global Macro" as that is a more common title

Comment: Perhaps http://quant.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited for this question?

Comment: although it doesn't qualify as an answer, http://www.georgesoros.com/books/the_crash_of_2008_and_what_it_means/ is a great reading for someone interested in macro-investments.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few books in the market on global macro strategies, the following could be useful:

- Bernad Baumohl (2012) The Secrets of Economic Indicators: Hidden
  Clues to Future Economic Trends and Investment Opportunities
- Greg Gliner (2014) Global Macro Trading: Profiting in a New World Economy

Also try reading [Burstein's book](http://www.globalmacroarbitrage.com/)